# how to design flutter Textfield border like this

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to design the flutter text field like this can anyone help me.

[image: 1]

[Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZUu0.png)

Comment: Please add, what have you tried so far. Maybe read this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-input

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your TextField inside the Theme Widget and the Material Widgets

*Increase elevation for shadow effect*

```
         Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.black,
            primaryColorDark: Colors.black,
          ),
          child: Material(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
            elevation: 5,
            shadowColor: Color(0XFF000000),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

it will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could warp it with a container and set

```dart
decoration: Boxdecoration(
border: ...
borderRadius: ...
boxShadow: ...
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `InputDecoration.collapsed` for `TextField` and wrap it with a container like this :

```
Container(
        height: 42,
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 16, 8),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Your Hint", hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.75),
              spreadRadius: 3,
              blurRadius: 0,
              offset: Offset(2, 2), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

it will look like this:

[image]